# How to make a function asynchronous?

Tags: dart, asynchronous

Why doesn't the execution of `f` in the following code happen asynchronously after the `main` function. I expect it to be scheduled for execution from the event loop. Returning some `Future` doesn't help either.

```
void f() async {
  print('f');
}


void main() {
  print('main start');
  f();
  print('main end');
}
```

Output:

```
main start
f
main end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking a function `async` doesn't make what's going on inside the function async or change how the caller handles it. Any synchronous code inside a function marked `async` will still be run synchronously until the first async function call is hit.

To call `print('f')` asynchronously, construct a new `Future`.

```dart
void f() {
  Future(()=>print('f'));
}


void main() {
  print('main start');
  f();
  print('main end');
}
```

---

Or you could construct the future in `main` if you'd like:

```dart
void f() {
 print('f');
}


void main() {
  print('main start');
  Future(f);
  print('main end');
}
```